How to redirect a page if URL parameters are not in URL on page load
I have a URL that I need to redirect away from if the page visitor does not have a specific parameter in the URL when they visit the page. This is the code I have, but it seems to only work one time in Firefox and not at all when Chrome or Edge.
The goal is that if the visitor has the gcl_customer_id parameter in the URL, they stay on the page. If there is no parameter in the URL when they visit the page, they need to be redirected away instantly.
I can only do this on the client side, in browser on page load. I have no ability to handle this server side.
How can I fix this code?
  <script>
    function checkForXYZId() {
      const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
      if (!urlParams.has('xyz_id')) {
        window.location.href = 'https://facebook.com'; 
      }
    }
    window.onload = checkForXYZId;
  </script>


Some notes: (1) I can't reproduce, it just works for me all the time in Chrome and Firefox. (2) If you still have problems, try if doing window.location.replace('https://facebook.com'); works better for you.

I appreciate the suggestion. Gave that a try, but no change. I also ensured I was using a chrome/edge browser free of extensions. Weird...

Solved it.
I am using a GoHighLevel based CRM. This code was originally inserted into a hidden field.
I moved the code to the Survey Footer which loads prior to the form fields. Seems to be working now!

Solved it. I am using a GoHighLevel based CRM. This code was originally inserted into a hidden field. I moved the code to the Survey Footer which loads prior to the form fields. Seems to be working now!
